# Start-Job not working when executed as part of a script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell Script that is designed to run Test-NetConnection continuously for a certain amount of time.

The script works great when executed through PSE or when I manually run the job from within PowerShell, but when I execute the command via a batch file or if I close the PowerShell window wile the job should still be going the script ends... Am I doing something wrong? What is the point of running something as a background job if it doesn't stay running in the background?

EDIT: I tried using the InvokeCommand with the -computername and -asjob flags but it doesn't work still and requires me to enable psremoting. I want to run the following script by executing a batch file that references it and then be able to let the PS window close so the job isn't interrupted by a log-off or another user possibly closing things oust

```
$TimetoRun = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input how long you want the script to run in hours'
$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $timeStart.AddSeconds($TimetoRun)

$Destination = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the Hostname or IP you want to test'
$Port = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the port you want the script to test'
$Interval = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the interval you want to test connection in seconds'

$scriptDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
param($scriptDir,$TimeStart,$TimeEnd,$Destination,$Port,$Interval)

Start-Transcript -Path "C:\Users\npayne\Desktop\TestNetConnection\Connectivity.log"
Write-Host "Start Time: $TimeStart"
write-host "End Time:   $TimeEnd"
Write-Host "Destination: $Destination"
Write-Host "Port: $Port"
Write-Host "Interval = $Interval seconds"
Do { 
$TimeNow = Get-Date
if ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd) {
Write-host "Net Connection Test Completed"
} else {
$Test = "$(Get-Date) - $(Test-NetConnection -Port $Port $Destination -InformationLevel Quiet)"
Write-Host $Test
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds $Interval
}
Until ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
Stop-Transcript
} -ArgumentList $scriptDir,$TimeStart,$TimeEnd,$Destination,$Port,$Interval
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Invoke-* (run code on remote machines), PSremoting is a requirement by design (as is being an admin on the remote host), and there is no getting around that, other than setting this script up as a logon script or scheduled task on the remote target.

In the PSE, PowerShell will autoload/resolve/process code sequentially with what it needs. In the consolehost, you have to make sure you add those resources, before you use them, i.e., .Net forms namespaces if you have form code in play.

There are only few commands you can run without PowerShell Remoting enabled. Invoke-* is not part of those.

Reference:

> • Tip: Work Remotely with Windows PowerShell without using Remoting or
> WinRM
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699046.aspx
>
> ```
> Some cmdlets have a –ComputerName parameter that lets you work with a remote 
> computer without using Windows PowerShell remoting. This means you can use 
> the cmdlet on any computer that is running Windows PowerShell, even if the 
> computer is not configured for Windows PowerShell remoting. These cmdlets 
> include the following:
>
> • Get-WinEvent
> • Get-Counter
> • Get-EventLog
> • Clear-EventLog
> • Write-EventLog
> • Limit-EventLog
> • Show-EventLog
> • New-EventLog
> • Remove-EventLog
> • Get-WmiObject
> • Get-Process
> • Get-Service
> • Set-Service
> • Get-HotFix
> • Restart-Computer
> • Stop-Computer
> • Add-Computer
> • Remove-Computer
> • Rename-Computer
> • Reset-ComputerMachinePassword
> ```

As for PowerShell jobs. You need to be using the correct one for your use case. There are several types (this does not obviate the need to PSRemoting to be enabled for code to run on remote hosts):

```
TABLE
Job Type        Description
--------        -----------
BackgroundJob   Started by using the Start-Job cmdlet.
RemoteJob       Started by using the AsJob parameter of the Invoke-Command cmdlet.
PSWorkflowJob   Started by using the AsJob parameter of a workflow.
PSScheduledJob  An instance of a scheduled job started by a job trigger.
CIMJob          Started by using the AsJob parameter of a cmdlet from a CDXML module.
WMIJob          Started by using the AsJob parameter of a cmdlet from a WMI module.
PSEventJob      Created by running Register-ObjectEvent and specifying an action with the Action parameter.
```

> See additional details
>
> [about_Jobs - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs)
>
> [about_Job_Details - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_job_details)
>
> [about_Scheduled_Jobs - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/about/about_scheduled_jobs)
>
> [about_Remote_Disconnected_Sessions - PowerShell ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_disconnected_sessions)
>
> [Using Windows PowerShell Jobs | Scripting Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-windows-powershell-job)

Comment: I understand the remotejob thing. I'm not needing it to work on remote machines I was just trying to get a process that would run immediately in the background. One of the work arounds was to run invoke-command locally. Didn't work. I'm going to try PSScheduledJob again to make sure I didn't miss anything. I'm still a bit confused of the purpose of a BackgroundJob that requires the current powershell interface to be open to run. that is more just hidden output then an actual background job.